# Running JAR file in C# without providing path to the PROCESS

Tags: java, c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I wanted help in Running `java` app from `c#` from a `jar` file. Some of the solutions that I saw include:

```
ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo (@"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe", @"-jar C:\Users\tinkzz\Documents\Eclipse\export\control_shift.jar");
            ps.UseShellExecute = false;
            Process.Start (ps);
```

This is the code which is working fine.

But I want to avoid adding path to the code. As I want the "jar-file" to be included in file executable(.exe in bin).

I am using `xamarin` IDE for mine `C#` console project. However I have `visual studio` as well. Can you please suggest a method to run the `jar` file by including it in `xamarin`/`visual studio` project.

Answer (score 1):

A jar is not inherently executable (even an "executable" jar- that's just a jar that has a manifest providing the default `main`). You need to provide the path to the executable (java.exe) in order for the operating system to know what executable to start. You can associate files with the extension .jar with a particular Java installation on Windows and then "execute" the jar by providing the path to the jar instead of the executable, but you'll need to set `UseShellExecute` to true in order to leverage that association.